# Importing XML into Cocoa issues

Tags: xml, cocoa

Here's an XML file I want to import into Cocoa:

```
 <?xml version='1.0'?>
    <Root xmlns='http://www.abc.uk' version='1.0' name='full'>
      <child1 version='2.0'>
        <value1>
           <user>abc</user>
           <pass>xyz</pass>
        </value1>
     </child1>
     <child2>
        <imp>12345</imp>
     </child2>
   </Root>
```

Now if I add all the XML info using the following type of code:

```
     NSXMLElement *root = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"Root"];
     [root addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"NSXMLElement        

     [root addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"version" stringValue:@"2.0"]];
     [root addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"name" stringValue:@"full"]];


     NSXMLElement *childElement1 = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"child1"];
     [childElement1 addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"version"   
         stringValue:@"2.0"]];
     [root addChild:childElement1];
     [childElement1 release];
```

This does not create the XML as I would want it to. The end XML looks like:

```
     <?xml version='1.0'?>
    <Root xmlns='http://www.abc.uk' version='1.0' name='full'>
      <child1 version='2.0'> </child1>
        <value1> </value1>
           <user>abc</user>
           <pass>xyz</pass>

          <child2></child2>
          <imp>12345</imp>

   </Root>
```

How do I enter it correctly ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `user` and `pass` elements to the `value` element, and the `value` element to the `child1` element, and the `imp` element to the `child2` element. From your output, it looks like you're just adding everything to the `Root` element.